# React Router Dom v4 Multiple Nested Routes On Home Activeclass

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I need multiple nested routes in react-router-dom in home Page

--- Home
--- Page 1
--- Page 2
--- About

I have home page that contains two subs the active class will be worked based the path Home/HomeNested page This my requirement.
But It work on The home page is active on page load if I click  nested homepage page the home page active gone.
code sandbox Link:https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-forked-71x4z?file=/example.js

Comment: pls make your question more clear

Comment: please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've debuged your code a bit. You've missed exact on '/' path. Please check nesting routes I've made in /topics/[route] for you here:

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-forked-dnvpj?file=/example.js)

Thank you for example of NavLink. I didn't even know about this component from react-router :p